# Heatmap gradient color error ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, heatmap

I am comparing two samples without replicates. I am struck at making the heatmap as the heatmap obtained only shows color for the genes with higher number of reads in blue color and the lower one in white when making the plot. I have tried changing the color scheme. Its not because of color scheme I guess.
for e.g.

```
                         variety 1       variety 2
```

gene_id_12345

```
                            25000     18000
```

So instead of showing gradient colors for there two its showing variety 1 in blue color and variety 2 as white. Happening for all the genes. Therefore I am getting a binary kind of graph. I am not very good with stats but have followed the manual completely.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what tools you're using to construct the heatmap. Please provide references to packages you're using (e.g. `library(ggplot2)`) and the code. Ideally, you would also drop in a snippet of the data which clearly demonstrates what's going wrong and how you're unable to resolve it.

Comment: Using library(ggplot2), library("RColorBrewer").Instead of heatmap.2(code),my package only has heatmap(code).cuz of this?error in data?

heatmap(exprs(vsd)[select,], col = hmcol, trace="none", margin=c(10, 6)) 

head(vsd)
ExpressionSet (storageMode: lockedEnvironment)
assayData:1 features, 2 samples 
element names:exprs 
protocolData:none
phenoData
sampleNames:variety1 variety2
varLabels:sizeFactor condition
varMetadata:labelDescription
featureData
featureNames:C-123
fvarLabels:disp_blind
fvarMetadata:labelDescription
experimentData:use 'experimentData(object)'
Annotation: